# how to get values that are returned in sql stored procedure to Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the results into a `DATASET`
When i am using `SELECT` the value is coming to DATASET, but if i am using `RETURN` `DATASET` is empty

```
SET @ReturnValue = 0  --Indicates Success       

Return @ReturnValue
```

How to get values that is returned using `RETURN` statement??

Answer (score 1):

Please look at books on-line for sample procedure call.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx

```
-- From BOL - sample procedure
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE checkstate @param varchar(11)
AS
IF (SELECT StateProvince FROM Person.vAdditionalContactInfo WHERE [BusinessEntityID] = @param)
     = 'WA'
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 2;
GO

-- Sample call
DECLARE @return_status int;
EXEC @return_status = checkstate @param = '2';
SELECT 'Return Status' = @return_status;
GO
```

I made two changes to the sample.

First, [ContactId] does not exist in my version of AW2012.  I added a correction on BOL.

Second, always use named parameters.  That way, the call is not dependent upon order.

GL

Answer (score 1):

You must add a parameter to your [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) with the direction [`ParameterDirection.ReturnValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See [Modifying Data with Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59x02y99%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an example.